# Tabla de multiplicar con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una tabla de multiplicar con javascript pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

Lo que quiero hacer es que no me borre el html y me muestra la tabla completa.

Tengo este código para mostrarlo pero como es obvio me borra el contenido del html:

```js
document.write();
```

Probé con un pero me muestra un solo resultado y no la tabla completa:

```js
document.getElementById();
```

Aqui podrán ver el código completo:

```js
function multi() {

    num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    num = parseInt(num);

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        multi = num * i;
        document.write(num + "x" + i + "=" + multi + "<br>");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="num">Introduce un número: </label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="num">

    <button onclick="multi()">MULTIPLICACIÓN</button>

    <p id="multi"></p>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código completo, para indetificar mas rapido el problema y poder ayudarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo:

- Obtén tanto el botón que invoca a la función como el espacio donde planeas mostrar la tabla de multiplicar a través de su `id` *(así mantienes mas limpio tu HTML)*
- No uses `document.write`, en su lugar emplea `innerHTML` para que por medio del id de una etiqueta de tu HTML le asignes contenido, en este caso puede ser a un `div` y así mantienes todo tu documento afectando solo el contenido de una etiqueta
- Cuando estés asignando el valor emplea `+=` para ir almacenando los valores de cada multiplicación derivado del uso del `for` y que te muestre cada renglón en lugar del último
- Genera el ciclo `for` dentro del evento `click` que se desencadena cuando el usuario presiona el botón
- En lugar de concatenar con el símbolo de `+` emplea la sintaxis de *template strings* para tener una sintaxis mas acortada y legible

  - Para este punto si necesitas que se procese la operación matemática; entonces escríbelo de este modo: **`${numero.value * i}`**

    - Donde `numero.value` es el acceso de la variable al valor del input donde el usuario escribe el número para generar la tabla de multiplicar
    - `i` es el iterador del ciclo `for`

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <label for="num">Introduce un número: </label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="num" />
    
        <button id="genera">MULTIPLICACIÓN</button>
    
        <div id="multi"></div>
    
    <script>
      let genera = document.getElementById("genera")
      let numero = document.getElementById("num")
      let lienzo = document.getElementById("multi")
    
      genera.addEventListener("click", () => {
        for(let i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
          lienzo.innerHTML += `${numero.value} * ${i} = ${numero.value*i} <br />`
        }
      })
    
    </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que cuando usas [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write) sobreescribe el contenido HTML inicial. Lo adecuado sería que iteres los resultados de la tabla de multiplicar concatenandolo en una sola cadena y luego de ello lo insertes dentro de un elemento preestablecido:

```js
const inputNum = document.getElementById("num")
const tablaMulti = document.getElementById("tabla-multi")

function multi() {
  const numero = parseInt(inputNum.value)
  
  let template = ''

  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      template += numero + "x" + i + "=" + numero * i + "<br>"
  }
  tablaMulti.innerHTML = template
}
```

```html
<label for="num">Introduce un número: </label>
<input type="number" name="" id="num">

<button onclick="multi()">MULTIPLICACIÓN</button>

<div id="tabla-multi"></div>
```